# Kakfa Producer - Spring Boot Application - Unable to Produce Messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am just learning spring boot and kakfa as well. I have explored a bit and configured a sample producer Application as below. However I am not able to publish the messages. 
Would be great if I get assistance on what is being missed here. I have started the zookeeper service and kakfa service and ensured that topic is available.

```
Config:

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import com.jpmorgan.sample.producer.KafkaProducer;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
    import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
    import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;

    @Configuration
    public class KafkaConfig {

        @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
        private String bootstrapServers;

        public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            // list of host:port pairs used for establishing the initial connections to the Kakfa cluster
            props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                    bootstrapServers);
            props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                    StringSerializer.class);
            props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                    StringSerializer.class);

            return props;
        }

        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
            return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaProducer sender() {
            return new KafkaProducer();
        }
    }


Producer Class:
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;

public class KafkaProducer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducer.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(String payload) {
        LOGGER.info("sending payload='{}'", payload);
        kafkaTemplate.send("test", payload);
    }
}

Sample Application Class:
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaProducerSampleApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaProducerSampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am just running through IntelliJ. And I see that the moneta boot has started

```
         main] n$WebApplicationLoggingAutoConfiguration : Enabled Moneta Request Logging with exclude-url-patterns: [], http.log-request-headers: [false], http.log-response-headers: [false], http.log-request-entity: [false], http.log-response-entity: [false] and http.max-entity-bytes: [1024]
2020-05-06 18:51:57.539  INFO 4952 --- [           main] c.j.m.b.a.s.cors.CorsAutoConfiguration   : Moneta CORS has been disabled because neither [moneta.cors.allowed-origins] nor [moneta.cors.allowed-origins-regex] has been set
2020-05-06 18:51:57.628  INFO 4952 --- [           main] .m.b.a.a.MonetaActuatorAutoConfiguration : Enabled Moneta defaults for Spring Boot Actuator
2020-05-06 18:51:57.677  INFO 4952 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter corsFilter was not registered (disabled)
2020-05-06 18:51:57.860  INFO 4952 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-06 18:51:57.956  WARN 4952 --- [           main] c.j.m.b.startup.ApplicationInfoLoader    : !!!! SEAL ID property [application.seal.id] should be provided as either as a system property or in the application properties file !!!!
2020-05-06 18:51:58.054  INFO 4952 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 4 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-05-06 18:51:58.111  INFO 4952 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-06 18:51:58.114  INFO 4952 --- [           main] c.j.s.KafkaProducerSampleApplication     : Started KafkaProducerSampleApplication in 2.547 seconds (JVM running for 4.376)
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you run the code? how are you running Kafka?

Comment: I am just running using Intellij. I dont see any exceptions. I see that the application has started 0 @RobinMoffatt : Please find the message above.

Comment: i can help you with @Karthi

Comment: Sure @harkesh : Could you please let m know what is missing herr

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `Sender.send()` from anywhere so why would you expect it to do anything?

Comment: Could you please suggest where should I have this function call . I am new to java and spring boot stuff. Got confused

Answer (score 2):

Try this way 
you don't need to annotate with @EnableKafka in producer config

Remove @Bean from producerConfigs then try i will work

```
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
```

Comment: if this still not working then can you share the proper error message that you getting

Comment: After modifying the changes, I executed again and I I still get the same message as I mentioned above. I am not getting any error or exception as such.

Comment: Is it something to do with the follwing     private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(String payload) {
        LOGGER.info("sending payload='{}'", payload);
        kafkaTemplate.send("helloworld.t", payload);